# More Issues With Units

Tags: grid-layouts, units

I have asked a couple questions here (and received terrific answers), and used that info.

I am trying to fulfill a request from a colleague that liked the results of Astronomy info I had done, but wanted it in a flat, 2D format (along with sun and mood data, but one task at a time.

I manged the grid ok enough (attached), but once again I cannot change the units associated with these quantities from g/cm^3 to kg/m^3. I have tried what others helped with in my previous questions, but, for whatever reason I'm not getting it....and if it's me, well, that's possible, but I am trying.

Can the units be changed, and if so how, because I am (once again) out of ideas. I have been looking at this in the documentation and online for a few days now and it's escaping me.

Thanks (again) for your help.

[image]

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code.  Post the output as an image, but the input as copyable.  It is failing because `UnitConvert` should take a `Quantity` as the input, not a grid.  You either need to `Map` the unit conversion to the appropriate level or use a replacement rule like `Text[<your code here>] /. q_Quantity :> UnitConvert[q, "Stones"/"Gallons"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = PlanetData[PlanetData[], {"Name", "Density"}] /. {p_, m_} :> {p, UnitConvert[m, "SIBase"]} // 
         Prepend[{"Name", "Density"}]

Grid[data, Frame -> All, Background -> LightYellow, ItemStyle -> {Automatic, 1 -> Bold}]
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed....I'm going to have to try and understand what you did here, because I was completely stuck, and I thank you for the help.

Comment: Rohit....I guess I didn't recognize your name. You help a LOT and I appreciate it. I try to understand what is provided, but sometimes it's not always clear. Nevertheless thank you for helping!

Comment: @fiz You are welcome. My answer and @Bob Hanlon's answer both use`/.` to do the unit conversion. `/.` is short for [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html).

Comment: Ok....thank you once again. I'm trying to learn this (and also Python as well)....ugh....but you're help is appreciated, and I do read it and take it to heart. Thanks Rohit!

Answer (score 3):

With a little more color:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

items = {"Image", "Name", "Density"};

(data = PlanetData[PlanetData[], items] /. 
     q_Quantity :> UnitConvert[q] // Prepend[items]) //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All, Background -> LightYellow, 
   ItemStyle -> {Automatic, 1 -> Bold}] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is BEAUTIFUL, and beautifully done. I only chose the other answer because it was all I needed and it arrived first, but I took this code and WILL utilize it, and appreciate it very much. I wish I knew this code as well as you both do....practice I guess.